# IntelliSense with C# (Unity) in VSCode disabling space to autocomplete

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, visual-studio-code, intellisense

I like intellisense however I don't like how when I finish typing something like a method name that has the name "Press" tries to autocomplete to "buttonpress" and when I press space bar to go to the next word or part of the code, it autocompletes to that and it's super frustrating. Is there any way to disable pressing spacebar for autocompleting but keep Tab to autocomplete?

Edit: I found the way to disable Enter or Tab for this (acceptSelectedSuggestion), but it doesn't list Space as one of the buttons that accepts the autocomplete suggestion.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is regarding configuring a VSCode shortcut and not about programming

Comment: @Brian On-topic is broader than only about programming. See https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic.  But +1 for explaining your vote.

Answer (score 0):

Go to File -> Preferences -> Settings -> Text Editor -> Suggestions -> Quick Suggestions -> Edit in settings.json and add this line

```
"editor.acceptSuggestionOnCommitCharacter": false
```

Comment: how do you change the commit character to tab instead of space?